# How to use interface's method

Tags: java

I have an interface `Cargo` and two classes that implement that interface, `Box` and `Loose`. In this interface i have two methods declared:

```
public interface Cargo {
    double getTotalValue();
    double getTotalWeight();
}
```

And the Loose class(Box is almost identical)

```
public class Loose implements Cargo{
    private double looseWeight;
    private double loosePricePerKg;

    public Loose(double looseWeight, double loosePricePerKg){
        this.looseWeight = looseWeight;
        this.loosePricePerKg = loosePricePerKg;
    }

    @Override
    public double getTotalValue() {
        return looseWeight * loosePricePerKg;
    }

    @Override
    public double getTotalWeight() {
        return looseWeight;
    }
}
```

I also have the Shipping interface

```
public interface Shipping<T> {
    boolean add(T o);
    T remove();
    List<T> getAll();
}
```

Now in my third class `CargoShipping`, that contains an ArrayList of Cargo, i'd like to return the total weight of all the cargo in that list. I thought of doing something like this:

```
    public class CargoShipping<Cargo> implements Shipping<Cargo>{
    @Override
    public boolean add(Cargo o) {
        cargo.add(o);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cargo remove() {
        Cargo ref = cargo.get(cargo.size() - 1);
        cargo.remove(cargo.size()-1);
        return ref;

    }

    @Override
    public List<Cargo> getAll() {
        return cargo;
    }
    public double getValue(){
        double value;
        for (Cargo c: cargo
             ) {
            value += c.getTotalWeight();
        }
        return value;
     }
}
```

But all i get from that is an error message, that says

```
Cannot resolve method 'getTotalWeight' in 'Cargo'
```

Is it that you can't use java interfaces in that way, or am i missing something?

To test it I use

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CargoShipping c1 = new CargoShipping(1000);
        c1.add(new Box(100, 100, 100));
        c1.add(new Loose(100, 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show more than a few snippets of code.  Include an [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Created a mock using your informations you gave and compiles just fine as long as all the classes are in the same package, make the interface methods public, to remove this little constraint.

Comment: @BigMike i have ArrayList, Collections and List imports. Anythin i'm missing? The IDE doesn't suggest anything else.

Comment: How are you populating your CargoShipping class.  Please provide an [mre] as asked,  That means it can be compiled, run, and the problem shown.

Comment: For one thing. Remove  `Cargo` from  `public class CargoShipping<Cargo>`  And add a `List<Cargo>` cargo in your class.

Comment: Remove useless generics, the underlying error is The type parameter 'Cargo' is hiding the type 'Cargo'.

Comment: Why is that?  I read, that the type has to be specified for the class, when implementing generic interface

Comment: *Why is that? I read, that the type has to be specified for the class, when implementing generic interface*.  Only if you're implemetning a generic class, which you are not.  The Cargo type isn't changing per instantiation of your class, so you don't need a generic type parameter.

Comment: @BigMike  recommend you consolidate this exchange in the form of an answer.  I'm bowing out.